# How to number sections: one, two, three

Tags: sectioning

I am attempting to number my sections with the English words: one, two, three, etc. For instance, the command \section{Hello} would produce:

**One Hello**

Is this even possible in LaTeX?

As an additional question, it would be great if I could put a colon after the number also, i.e.,

**One: Hello**

Comment: Sounds complicated... you must teach LaTeX to count in English... would be much easier in Chinese where numbers are broken down into constant bits. I will try answering sooner or later, but no guarantee of success :).

Comment: You need to use [`fmtcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount) and add `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Numberstring{section}}`.

Comment: Thank you, @Werner. That is exactly what I was looking for. If the question is a duplicate, I apologize. I did look all over here for an answer, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Oh. Boo. I spent such a long time devising a macro that already exists :(.

Comment: The macro seems to work, and supports any integer with absolute value strictly less than a billion, negative numbers therein included. Will post an answer to the other question.